# Перебор цикла в php и отображение в 2 или в 5 рядов

Tags: php, html, foreach, for

Возник такой вопрос, есть цикл, который перебирает нужные данные для отображения (пример Города).

Делаем обычный перебор:

```
<div class="cities">
<?php
foreach ($arElemets as $value):?>
<div class="name"> <a href="#"><?=$value;?></a></div>
<?;endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

ПО верстке у меня идет таким образом, что нужно разместить по 2 элемента (из перебора) в 1 div class = cities, пример ниже:

```
    <div class="cities">
      <div class="name">
                          <a href="#">Москва</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="name">
                                <a href="#">Перь</a>
                            </div>
</div>
    <div class="cities">
      <div class="name">
                          <a href="#">Москва</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="name">
                                <a href="#">Перь</a>
                            </div>
</div>
```

НО сейчас получается что я могу перебрать только в одном диве (cities) Все  и не могу разделить их по 2 элемента в блок div class="cities"

Вопрос, как сделать перебор таким образом, чтобы он каждые 2 элемента оформлял именно в класс ?

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, просто разбить массив, используя функцию [array_chunk()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-chunk.php), которая принимает первым аргументом исходный массив, а вторым - длину создаваемых "подмассивов" (в вашем случае 2)

```
foreach (array_chunk($array, 2) as $cities) {
    echo '<div class="cities">';
    foreach ($cities as $city) {
        echo '<div class="name"><a href="#">'.$city.'</a></div>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Таким вариантом можно разбить и на 2 и на 5 длину массивов?

Comment: Да, можно и на 2, и на 5, и на сколько угодно

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло)